# Looping through elements in a div in CsQuery

Tags: c#, csquery

I'm trying to open an HTML file, loop through the divs that match a certain criteria, and then loop through the p tags that match a certain criteria within those divs.

```
CQ dom = CQ.CreateFromFile("page.html");
CQ document_divs = dom["div"];
document_divs.Each((i,document_div) =>
{
    string divid = document_div.Id;
    if (divid.Contains("page"))
    {
        CQ page_ptags = document_div["p"];
        page_ptags.Each((j, page_ptag) =>
        {
            lblOutput.Text = page_ptag.Id;
        });

    }

});
```

It is selecting the divs fine, but I'm not sure how to select the p tags within a div. I know there is something wrong with this line:

```
CQ page_ptags = document_div["p"];
```

But what should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CQ page_ptags = document_div.Cq().Find("p");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking throw a CQ object, each elements will be type of IDom. 
That's why you need or wrap it in CQ object, or use native Dom functions to work with.